# How to make X server stop in case of kernel panic?

Tags: kernel, xorg

How can it be done?

When computer crashes (quite often due to experiments with kernel) - it just locks up...

What i get: hang up. Just freeze, and then (because of panic=) reboot

What i want: x-server immediately stops so i can see whats written console.

Is it possible, or it's impossible to stop x-server in case of a crash

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1):

If you do kernel experiments, how about using kdump? That would give you more than just a fleeting glimpse of a second or two.

See https://ubuntu.com/server/docs/kernel-crash-dump

Comment: nice idea, but in my case - i'm trying to make system as simple as possible.... - made kernel fully monolithic, got rig of a lot of stuff i dont use. so - exiting xorg is better solution

Comment: You can always remove it again when your experiments are done. But for debugging you need tools, otherwise it's just poking in the dark.

Comment: Alternatively, set up a serial console and watch your kernel messages from there (using a second computer, of course).

Comment: Serial console is a good idea.... arduino+screen+sd card... but how do i do that?